# Gridview within a placeholder

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview, contentplaceholder

i have currently create a user web control with a dataview in it
currently this is the gridview

```
<div class="col-md-12">
        <asp:GridView id="dtgrid1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False"  AutoGenerateDeleteButton="True" AutoGenerateEditButton="True" AutoGenerateSelectButton="True" CellPadding="4" ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="Horizontal" AllowPaging="True" width="100%" ShowFooter="True" ShowHeaderWhenEmpty="True" EmptyDataText="No records Found">
            <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#284775" />
            <Columns>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="ID" HeaderText="ID" ItemStyle-Width="30" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Descripcion" HeaderText="Descripcion" ItemStyle-Width="250" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Monto" HeaderText="Monto" ItemStyle-Width="150" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Fecha" HeaderText="Fecha" ItemStyle-Width="150" />
            </Columns>
            <EditRowStyle BackColor="#999999" />
            <FooterStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
            <HeaderStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
            <PagerStyle BackColor="#284775" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
            <RowStyle BackColor="#F7F6F3" ForeColor="#333333" />
            <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#E2DED6" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333" />
            <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#E9E7E2" />
            <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#506C8C" />
            <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#FFFDF8" />
            <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#6F8DAE" />
        </asp:GridView>
    </div>
```

that gridview is in a webuser control with other cotrols and divs, everythings show as it should but the gridviews
this is the code on the onload event

```
If Not Page.IsPostBack Then
            dim dgv1datatable as new DataTable
            With dgv1datatable
                .Columns.Add(New DataColumn("ID", GetType(Integer)))
                .Columns.Add(New DataColumn("Descripcion", GetType(String)))
                .Columns.Add(New DataColumn("Monto", GetType(Double)))
                .Columns.Add(New DataColumn("Fecha", GetType(Date)))
            End With
            Session("dgv1dt") = dgv1datatable
            dtgrid1.DataSource = DirectCast(Session("dgv1dt"), DataTable)
            dtgrid1.DataBind()
            dtgrid1.Visible = True
        End If
```

but it's now showing the gridview but if i insted place the gridview where the placeholder should be the gridview shows any help please?

EDIT
im going to try and explain better the issue
this is where the gridview should've within a webusercontrol that is in a placeholder
[image]
so since it wasn't showing i decided to delete the placeholder and place the gridview in the same place and it did appear
[image]

Comment: Your datatable is never loaded with any data, how do you expect anything to show up at all?

Comment: On a separate note, please don't store datatables into sessions

Comment: ok, let's say the database not been loaded is the problem, it should atleast say that "No records Found" message which did when i placed the gridview in the website it self instead of the webusercontrol

Answer (score 0):

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" CacheExpirationPolicy="Sliding" 
    ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:catalog %>"     
        SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM YourDB"></asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Comment: i want the gridview to be empty since the user is gonna populate it